# Why I can't use update-alternatives to select Python 2 or 3?

Tags: python, update-alternatives

Is there a particular reason on why `update-alternatives` is not working with `Python` since ubuntu comes bundled with different versions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is, `python` versions aren't fully compatibile. If you set `3.3` version as your default, the applications made for `2.7` could not work.

Comment: Exactly. Python 2 and 3 aren't considered alternatives. They're completely different things.

Comment: @Oli Great... except that python 2.x automatically symlinks itself to /usr/bin/python, which IMO is the wrong behavior since they aren't alternatives.

Comment: @Powerlord, No, it's not a wrong behaviour, as `python` is intended to always mean Python 2 and Python 3 expected to always be referred to as `python3`. I saw a note about this somewhere in a PEP or in Python mailing list (can't remember exactly what's the source).

Comment: @Hibou57 I think that in one or two years, they'll change meaning and python will be symbolic link to python3. That is in Arch Linux.

Answer (score -3):

Or maybe you can.

**Important Note:** The solution presented bellow (with `update-alternatives`) may **break** your system.
 If things break, try to fix them and keep python 3, report the fix you made to the correct bug-reports sites and help the community to grow; or *move back* to python 2. At the end of the answer I'll add a simple command to move back in case you need.

If you just want to change python for your own user, not the system, you can use an alias.

**Solution 1: alias**

Add this line into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias python=python3
```

And that is it. You don't need to read bellow.

**Solution 2: update-alternatives**

If alias is not what you are looking for, and you really want to change the default of the whole system, then keep reading.

First check your python version:

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

Use this commands to install alternatives (run as `root` or use `sudo`)

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

Then configure the version with (again, run also `root` or use `sudo`):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

Now check the version:

```
# python -V
Python 3.5.3
```

When you run the above command, you can choose `selection number: 0` or `2` to pick python 3. If things break, run again and pick number `1` to go back to python 2.

---

Good readings:

[python3 statement](https://python3statement.org/practicalities/)

[Hack-a-Day](https://hackaday.com/2018/08/15/stop-using-python-2-what-you-need-to-know-about-python-3/)

[The Register News](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/09/09/the_end_of_python_2_2020/)

Comment: This will break your system **hard**.  ***DO NOT attempt this.***

Comment: Maybe on ubuntu. As long term user of Debian and system admin, I'm experimenting with one of my systems for a month now and nothing breaks. I'll update if something goes wrong.

Comment: That breaks Debian too because not everything's undergone a Python 2 -> Python 3 conversion.  Keep the Debian specific 'fixes' for this out of Ubuntu, because I can 100% guarantee you that doing this right now in Debian Unstable or in Ubuntu will ***explode the system's ability to operate**.

Comment: Also check: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177899/why-does-apt-get-in-ubuntu-still-want-to-install-python-2-7/177903#comment1001673_177903 and https://gist.github.com/patrickmmartin/5b6b2ddecd29d6a1b2ffee2d8eea31ec and of course about the apt break: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt . No need to cause *alarm*, just discuss what will break instead of trying to add fear to people.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but my current experiment (real server running 24/7 for a month now) is not broken. Maybe other packages that are not so necessary to my own system and are not installed breaks and I don't have them to check. Anyway, it is working fine.

Comment: Also: in my answer, at the end, I added a note about "system breaking". So, to avoid these negative downvotes, I'll edit and move the note to the begin of the answer as a precaution.

Comment: Even if it doesn't break things on your system —per my comment half a decade ago on the accepted answer— **Python 2 and 3 aren't alternatives**. That's the only answer to this question. Yes, *ofcourseyoucan* train butterflies to write Python 4 with cosmic rays but that's not why there isn't an alternative for `/usr/bin/python` in Ubuntu. Alternatives are for drop-in replacements.

Comment: And regarding what doing this will break, run `apt rdepends python | grep -vE ': python' | wc -l` and you'll see the number of things the depend on Python 2, many expecting `/usr/bin/python` to accept a Python2 syntax. That's a count of 952 here on 19.04. This is just bad advice. Leave `/usr/bin/python` alone.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution with `alias` and a warning about the possible system break and how to revert. Thanks for the input. Again: I'm running a 5 years old server, upgraded to the last Debian buster and it doens't break, even running apache. The future is python 3. The apps that depend on python 2 are encouraged to use `#!/usr/bin/env python2` instead of just python, and that will help in the transition. This answer may not be fully adequate today for some systems, but it is going to work during transition and it will be irrelevant in some years as python 3 assumes the default. Tks